# Writing a series of std::conditional with the same condition

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a more compact way to write the following?

```
typedef typename std::conditional< condition, type_A1, type_B1 > type_C1;
typedef typename std::conditional< condition, type_A2, type_B2 > type_C2;
typedef typename std::conditional< condition, type_A3, type_B3 > type_C3;
...
```

Where the condition is same, and `type_Ax`, `type_Bx`, `type_Cx` for different lines are different.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for a macro

Comment: Can I define a macro that only works in the scope of a class?

Comment: No, macros dont obey scopes.

Comment: No.  A macro is globaly scoped so it is available everywhere after its definition.

Comment: The `typedef` statements you generate with your macro will hold the same scope as those you're writing by hand now. As for the macro itself, you can just `#undef` if when you're done.

Comment: Good point LRIO

Comment: Put `type_Ai` and `type_Bi` in a tuple then return either tuple based on `condition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<class A, class B> using select = std::conditional_t<condition, A, B>;

using C1 = select<A1, B1>; // or typedef if you really like that syntax
// etc.
```